# Fetching Siebel Business service list and methods from java application console

Tags: java

I want to fetch the list of Business Services and its methods from Siebel application from Java application console. It will be great, if you can point me to some resources on the same which can help me achieve this requirement.

Comment: Firstly, im sorry you have to work with Siebel. Secondly, show us what you have already tried to do (even if it doesn't work)

Comment: Till now I have tried to execute a specific Siebel business service, just to try accessing Siebel from Java. But my requirement is show list of Siebel business service, so that one can choose whatever Business Service he\she want to execute.

Comment: Specify the version of siebel you are working with.

Comment: I am working with Siebel 8.1 version

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you [Siebel 16: RESTful API](http://www.siebelhub.com/main/2016/05/siebel-16-rest.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but this is specific to the Siebel IP16 version (latest). I need to work with older versions for now.